# Spider a website, what the fastest method other than wget

Tags: wget

I use `wget --spider -l4 -r --delete-after` option.
I realise the crawling rate is relatively slow.

my page have page 2,3,4,5 etc (link from page 1) of that category.

If i just want hit the website page once, but not retrieve the html, what should I use to do it the fastest way.

In general is to able to touch all the internal links, to make them load once(to generate my cache). I don't need crawl the html. any idea how to do this the best fast way. The site are all interlinked

```
Main site
 > Category
   > Different Posts of Category
      > Pages of Post
```

I want able crawl all of the links of the site itself, in the fastest way ( don't need download anything) just like a google bot spider around.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest trying `mget` http://rockdaboot.github.io/mget/

`mget` is `wget`-workalike, but multithreaded. So it can make use of parallel connections to speed things up. It also has more-sophisticated compression support. If you start using it much I think you’ll find that it generally just works faster overall.